# Does TDengine database support BLOB data type?

Tags: database, blob, tdengine

Currently, I'm using TDengine in a project and want to have a BLOB column to store a variable of unstructured binary data(e.g. CSV files). Does TDengine support this kind of data type for columns or tags like MySQL which has TINYBLOB, MEDIUMBLOB, and LONGBLOB, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

TDengine supports the binary type and no more than 16K bytes length.